# Replacing manual data with database records in Angular controller

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, datatable

I only started Angular recently so still wobbling.
I've got some code that is populating a table with data manually and would like to actually load it from a Mysql/PHP database that I have on PhpMyAdmin.
I have gone through many examples online that load data via $http but in this case, the code that I have has some additional parameters that confuse me on how to properly call up the data from the database.

```
function() {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.table").controller("nutritionController", ["$mdEditDialog", "$q", "$scope", "$timeout", function(e, t, a, o) {
    a.selected = [],
    /* BACKUP CODE a.limitOptions = [5, 10, 15]*/
    a.limitOptions = [25, 50, 150, 300],
    a.options = {
        rowSelection: !1,
        multiSelect: !1,
        autoSelect: !1,
        decapitate: !1,
        largeEditDialog: !1,
        boundaryLinks: !1,
        limitSelect: !0,
        pageSelect: !1
    }, a.query = {
        order: "name",
        limit: 50,
        page: 1
    }, a.desserts = {
        count: 3,
        data: [{
            name: "Frozen yogurt",
            type: "Ice cream",
            calories: {
                value: 159
            },
            fat: {
                value: 6
            },
            carbs: {
                value: 24
            },
            protein: {
                value: 4
            },
            sodium: {
                value: 87
            },
            calcium: {
                value: 14
            },
            iron: {
                value: 1
            }
        }, {
            name: "Ice cream sandwich",
            type: "Ice cream",
            calories: {
                value: 237
            },
            fat: {
                value: 9
            },
            carbs: {
                value: 37
            },
            protein: {
                value: 4.3
            },
            sodium: {
                value: 129
            },
            calcium: {
                value: 8
            },
            iron: {
                value: 1
            }
        }, {
            name: "Eclair",
            type: "Pastry",
            calories: {
                value: 262
            },
            fat: {
                value: 16
            },
            carbs: {
                value: 24
            },
            protein: {
                value: 6
            },
            sodium: {
                value: 337
            },
            calcium: {
                value: 6
            },
            iron: {
                value: 7
            }
        }]
    }
```

Here are my questions:
- How should my "**nutrition.php**" file look like to properly load data from nutrition table? 
- How can I properly alter the code above to get data from "**nutrition.php**"?
- How can I make "**count**" value dynamic depending on how many records in the table instead of having to alter it manually as it is now.

Thanks.

Comment: have you create the php file already? do you mind to share it?

Comment: @HastaDhana Will share as soon as I create it, sorry for late reply, thanks.

Comment: @HastaDhana I have added the php file in a new question which I asked in a clearer way if you're keen to have a look...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852754/dynamic-data-for-ng-table