# Dynamic data for ng table

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

This piece of code is working properly but I need to replace the data section with values from MySQL table using PHP:

```
function() {
"use strict";
angular.module("app.table").controller("nutritionController", ["$mdEditDialog", "$q", "$scope", "$timeout", function(e, t, a, o) {
    a.selected = [],
    a.limitOptions = [25, 50, 150, 300],
    a.options = {
        rowSelection: !1,
        multiSelect: !1,
        autoSelect: !1,
        decapitate: !1,
        largeEditDialog: !1,
        boundaryLinks: !1,
        limitSelect: !0,
        pageSelect: !1},
    a.query = {
        order: "stu",
        limit: 50,
        page: 1},
    a.desserts = {
         count: 2, 
         data: [{
            stu: "yada1", 
            mod: "yada1",
            cat: "yada1",
            com: "yada1",
            cru: "yada1",
            for: "yada1",
            con: "yada1",
            cmt: "yada1",
        }, {
            stu: "yada2", 
            mod: "yada2",
            cat: "yada2",
            com: "yada2",
            cru: "yada2",
            for: "yada2",
            con: "yada2",
            cmt: "yada2",
        }] 
        }
        }])
        }()
```

I would like to use PHP/MySQL to replace "data" section with data from a MySQL table. I tried this but it kept returning errors:

```
a.desserts = {
count: 2,
data: function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("/URL/maindb.php")
.then(function (response) {$scope = response.data.records})
}
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$result = $conn->query("SELECT stu, mod, cat, com, cru, for, con, cmt FROM maintable");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"stu": "' . $rs["stu"]  . '",';
$outp .= '"mod": "'  . $rs["mod"]  . '",';
$outp .= '"cat": "'  . $rs["cat"]  . '",'; 
$outp .= '"com": "'  . $rs["com"]  . '",'; 
$outp .= '"cru": "'  . $rs["cru"]  . '",'; 
$outp .= '"for": "'  . $rs["for"]  . '",'; 
$outp .= '"con: "'   . $rs["con"]  . '",'; 
$outp .= '"cmt": "'  . $rs["cmt"]  . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

 echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: There's `json_encode` method.

Comment: Oy, do not try creating your own json, you'll run into so many problems. json_encode is a lot easier.

Comment: I am using json_encode now and php file is parsing json strings properly (tested it separately). Though for some reason controller doesn'f find and display data, it's just en empty table with only headers. I'm sure script in front of 'data:' is not ok...